# What is ECFirmwareMajorRelease in registry?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Can anyone tell me what ECFirmwareMajorRelease stands for?

The key can be found in the registry at
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an [System Management BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/SMBios) information field. [This](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/D/6/5D6EAF2B-7DDF-476B-93DC-7CF0072878E6/SMBIOS.doc) is a Microsoft document that explains SMBios support status in Windows.

"EC" is deacronymized as "Embedded Controller" and means a chip that processes some model-specific hardware events and also interprets ACPI pseudocode. (At least everything I found on the web refers to EC in this way. Also EC references are mostly found with ThinkPad laptops. [This](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Embedded_Controller_Firmware) is a small explanation of what it does on ThinkPads).